# Two players game, problem

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I have this type of problem: two boys have to divide 10 playstation games. The strategy is that first one choose a game, then the second another and so on, by having a common goal to be both "the most happy they can". Obviously the two boys have different tastes about the games, so for each game they could have different utility. I want to ask if a problem like that could be solved with Game Theory, and if yes which part of Game Theory I have to look at. Since it is very long theory, and less time ahahah.

Thanks to all, have a nice week :)

Comment: I'd start by reading about the cake-cutting problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_cake-cutting

Comment: If both boys only want to maximize their own happiness, wouldn't each choose the available game they like most, independently of what the other thinks? Or is there more to this problem?

Comment: You have described an alternating move game.  The trouble is, there are lots of possibilities depending on what the two boys preferences are.  For example, if they both agree on the ranking of the games, I think a standard strategy would be to take the best available game.  If you disagree, there might be more room for strategy, say you take your second best game first, because you know he likes it, but doesn't like your favorite game. (But I'm not sure that's an equlibrium) And it matters if you know the other boy's ranking or not.